# Javascript Memory Management Using Global Arrays of THREE.JS Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, three.js, webgl

I have a a question that's been bothering me for some time.

I am using the three.js webgl library to render a large scene with many textures and meshes.

This question is not necessarily bound to webgl, but more javascript arrays and memory management.

I am basically doing this:

```
var modelArray = [];

var model = function(geometry,db_data){
  var tex   = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture.jpg');
  var mat   = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:tex})
  this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,mat);
  this.db   = db_data;
  scene.add(this.mesh);
};

function loadModels(model_array){
  for(i=0;i<geometry.length;i++){
    modelArray.push(new model(model_array[i]['geometry'],model_array[i]['db_info']));
  }
}

loadModels();
```

Am I being inefficient here? Am I essentially doubling up the amount of memory being used since I have the mesh loaded to the scene and an array. Or does the model (specifically the model.mesh) object in the array simply point to a singular memory block?

Should I just create an array of mesh ids and reference the scene objects, or is it ok to add the mesh to the scene and an array?

Thanks in advance and I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Are you refactoring for the sake of it or have you encountered a performance or memory issue?

Comment: My memory usage gets exponentially higher for every model. Not only gpu memory but also the browser tabs memory which just seems way to high. That's why. I am still curious to see if assigning objects to an array is a serious memory hit, or does it simply create a reference to the (in this case mesh) object which is very large.

Comment: I have experienced off-topic memory issues related to allocated memory persistence through refreshes which I thought was impossible.

Comment: Anything is possible when the GPU is involved. :)

Comment: This is not good news lol =[

Comment: However I would like to get back to the original question. Does adding an object to an array double up allocated memory?

Comment: It should not. It should only allocated storage for the amount of pointers to the same objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that jumps out at me is this:

```
var tex   = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture.jpg');
var mat   = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map:tex})
```

If you are loading the same texture every time you create a new model, that could create a lot of overhead (and it can also be pretty slow). I would load the texture(s) and corresponding material(s) you need outside of your loop once.

Your `modelArray` is a list of plain `model` objects, each of which has a pointer to the corresponding `mesh` object (and `db` object). The `scene` has a pointer to the same `mesh` object so you are not exploding your memory use by cloning meshes.

It's possible that your memory use is just because your mesh geometries take up a lot of memory. Try loading your models one by one while watching memory usage; perhaps you have one that is unexpectedly detailed.

Comment: I do cache materials, geometries and textures ( though for textures i was really hoping i could reuse a texture at variable repeat settings but cannot =[ ). I'm glad to hear that a pointer is created in this situations =] I guess that's what I'll do, load the objects one by one and see whats causing this. Thanks for the input.